# About the plot of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

The graph of this differential equation $\cfrac{dA}{dt}=A(2-\cfrac{A}{5000})$, at first seems exponential but then it becomes a constant equal to $10000$.

The reason of this constant behavior is due to the term $\cfrac{-A^2}{5000}$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Think of the shape of polynomials.  Then 2A - A^2/5000 Will be inverse u shaped.

Comment: When $A=10000$, the parenthesis vanishes and $\frac{\mathrm dA}{\mathrm dt}=0$, which trivially integrates to $A=\text{const}$.

Comment: @Moo I didn't solve for $A$ I just plotted using Mathematica

Comment: @Moo oo, it depends, one needs to analyze their stability:)